# Accept request with large amount of inputs (thousands)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Have an application that requires to submit a request with hundreds/thousands of inputs.

It seems like Laravel has a limit on the number of parameters on requests.

Here are some pictures of current request state:

- [image]
- [image]

Arrays don't go over 48 and last arrays don't go over 47.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to increase the limit - but you can serialize the form with javascript then send it through just one input as text.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate. Javascript it is then haha, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit you reached is `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` which is by default 4000.

There might be another configuration in your server too (`apache`, `nginx`,...).

I never had to increase it, so I dont know if it is a good idea to do so.

As JCode said, might be a good solution to try and compress the input firsts and take in count the  execution time limit.

Comment: Doesn't seem to need another configuration. But compression looks like a better solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real limit with Laravel, but with PHP
Look at the variable : max_input_vars in php.ini
it should do the job
try

```
max_input_vars = 10000
```

or more
But sending a json string may be a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
max_input_vars = 15000

max_input_vars in php.ini which is by default 4000.
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a way to increase the limit in Laravel itself - but you can serialize the form with javascript then send it through just one input as text.